# Visual Studio Git prompts for credentials

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-clone

I recently started working on a private Git repository. I need to clone the repository by HTTPS URL. From the command line it asks for login and pass and cloning works OK, but once I clone the same URL from Visual Studio 2013 SP3, I receive a prompt from credential, which I cannot satisfy. I enter the same login info into the windows credential prompt, but I still receive the same credential prompt again and then it tells me that credential are incorrect.

I guess the windows prompt may add domain info to the login information.

How can I clone the repository from Visual Studio and what's may go wrong in this GUI case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, I found out that this was a firewall problem. It declined authorization requests.